# Script Alert not popup in Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, popup, alert

I developed laravel 5.4 for file upload.if i upload it need to pop up te sucess alert but it is not appear in here.

Here is my Layout in Laravel 5.4

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        @yield('content')
    </div>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the UploadController`s necessary part

```
else if($validator -> passes()){
        if(Input::file('filenam')->isValid()){
            $extention=Input::file('filenam')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename=rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extention;

            $destinationPath='up_file';
            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

            $notification = array(
                'message' => 'File Uploaded Successfully',
                'alert-type' => 'success'
                );

            return Redirect::to('upload')->with($notification);
        }
        else{
            $notification = array(
                'message' => 'File is not Valid!',
                'alert-type' => 'error'
                );

            return Redirect::to('upload')->with($notification);
```

as well as here is the view`s script part

```
    <script>
    @if(Session::has('message'))
    var type ="{{ Session::get('alert-type', 'info')}}";
    switch(type){
        case 'success':
        toastr.success("{{ Session::get('message')}}");
        break;

        case 'error': 
        toastr.error("{{ Session::get('message')}}");
        break;
    }
    @endif
</script>
```

Can anyone suggest the problem here.
Thank you.

Comment: can you dump Session::get('alert-type') in blade what is the output?

Comment: Sir are you suggestion to drop that?

Comment: No, Please check you session variable having value or not? just echo or print your session variable and check is your session data have value or not?

Comment: sir i dont understand what you are saying..sorry

Comment: You are using {{ Session::get('alert-type', 'info')}}, {{ Session::get('alert-type')}} is enough to get type right?

Comment: i change it either but that success alert does`t appear ..i hope i have no insert javascript links to my code..ryt?.because the tutorial i refereed he added javascript and ajax links as well.is that the reason?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are checking if `Session::has('message')` but you did not save the variable to the `Session`. But instead you just pass a `$notification` variable which is also not accessible to your view because you just did a `with($notification)`. `With()` will either need 2 arguments like `with('name', $value)` or `withName($value)` for your view to access the variable.

To solve your problem, do something like this in your Controller

```
$notification = array(
    'message' => 'File Uploaded Successfully',
    'alert-type' => 'success'
);

// saves $notification to the Session object
session()->put($notification); // or  \Session::put($notification); whichever you prefer

return Redirect::to('upload');
```

And in your view,

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <script>
        var type ="{{ Session::get('alert-type') }}";
        var msg = "{{ Session::get('message') }}";
        switch(type){
            case 'success':
                toastr.success(msg);
                break;

            case 'error': 
                toastr.error(msg);
                break;
        }
    </script>
@endif
```